# List Index Glyph Font and getAttributes()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am unable to set the font style of a font list index glyph to match an existing. Seems to be stuck with the default. Further, when I copy getAttributes() to a new list item attributes, the before/after spacing of the listItem paragraph before/after doesn't match the source item, either.  I have googled the font issue and seem to find that it is not possible, but I submitted a feature request at the issue tracker and they sent me here and closed the ticket.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Tks!

```
     if (row[0]=='CombinedAdditionalProvisions') {
        var listItems = bodyOfNewFile.getListItems();
        for (var item of listItems){
          note += bodyOfNewFile.getChildIndex(item)+item.getText()+'\n\n';
          if (item.getText().includes('<<! '+row[0].toUpperCase()+' !>>')) {
            var chIndex = bodyOfNewFile.getChildIndex(item)
            var attrib = bodyOfNewFile.getChild(chIndex).getAttributes();
            //ui.alert(JSON.stringify(attrib), ui.ButtonSet.OK);
            var indEnt = bodyOfNewFile.getChild(chIndex).getIndentEnd();
            var indFir = bodyOfNewFile.getChild(chIndex).getIndentFirstLine();
            var indSta = bodyOfNewFile.getChild(chIndex).getIndentStart();
            var nestLev = bodyOfNewFile.getChild(chIndex).getNestingLevel();
          }
        }

        var newItem = bodyOfNewFile.insertListItem(chIndex+1, 'test1');
        newItem.setAttributes(attrib);
        newItem.setNestingLevel(nestLev);
        newItem.setIndentEnd(indEnt)
        newItem.setIndentFirstLine(indFir)
        newItem.setIndentStart(indSta)
```

Comment: I gather you working with a Google Document but I don't see any reference to DocumentApp.

Comment: Yes.  Google docs.  I have a numbered list in the body.

Comment: can you share the full code in order to try it out?

Comment: I have unfortunately already edited it to work around the problem.  Basically what I was trying to do was the same thing as if your cursor were on a paragraph in a list and you press enter.  Create another item with the next number in the sequence with the same formatting.  The list, by the way, was intended (123ab456, want to make c).  When I add a new list item, and set it to nesting 2, it uses default settings,  I was able to set everything but the "d" glyph defaulted to arial and I was unable to change it to match everything else.

Comment: The workaround, by the way, was to add a bunch of list items with the formatting like it should be in the template document, fill them in, and delete the ones that arent used.

Comment: So did you find a solution for this? If so, can you post it as the correct answer so more people can benefit from it.

Comment: Hi, i have found an issue on Google Issue Tracker that has been reported internally. Go there and star it to follow the resolution. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765756

Comment: I would most definitely not say I have a proper solution as much as a rediculous work-around.  Just make an excess of items in the template document and edit the content.  Delete the unused ones when done.